# Merge two pandas dataframes in python with a common column and with condition on string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two dfs in python :

```
df1

    folder_name   name
0   f1          aa
1   g1          bb


df2   
    name        icon
0   aa          i1
1   bb          i2
2   aadoq       i3
3   bbaddd      i4
```

Desired output:

```
df   
    folder_name  name    icon
0   f1           aa      i1
1   g1           bb      i2
2   f1           aadoq   i3
3   g1           bbaddd  i4
```

I tried merging them but it seemed wrong

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on='name',how='right')
```

i am getting :

```
      folder_name  name    icon
  0   f1           aa      i1
  1   g1           bb      i2
  2   NAN          aadoq   i3
  3   NAN          bbaddd  i4
```

So if the prefix string in df2 name column matches any name column itme in df1 i want that folder name to be there for that name column in output

Comment: It's `df2.merge(df1, on='name', how='left')`, we've already been over this :-)

Comment: @coldspeed, that doesn't accomplish OPs purpose. That's how they are currently getting the undesired result.

Comment: @G.Anderson Ah, my bad, I glossed over this post and assumed that was their expected o/p. I will reopen.

Comment: Your example has inconsistent folder name ('d1' at the beginning and 'g1' rest of the example. Please, correct that)

Comment: changed the question thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, here are the prerequisites I got

1. Python (I used version 3, but should not be much different for version 2)
2. Pandas data frames
3. The folder name is not restricted to the length=2

Here is my Python code. I used the Python regex module. I selected the "name" list from both dataframes, checked if any name in dataframe 1 matches the name in dataframe 2 (match in python regex means to match from the beginning of the string). Created a new list called MappedName based on these criteria where there is a match use the matched name value from dataframe 1 if not, use the name value from dataframe 2. Added this list as a new column to dataframe 2. Used the 'name' column from dataframe 1 and 'MappedName' column from dataframe 2 for merge criteria.

I added one extra data point to the dataframe 2 to show what happens when there is no match with the regular expressions.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import re

df1=DataFrame({'folder_name':['f1','g1'],'name':['aa','bb']})
df2=DataFrame({'name':['aa','bb','aadoq','bbaddd','ding'],'icon':['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5']})
df1_name_list=df1['name']
df2_name_list=df2['name']
MappedName=[]
for name2 in df2_name_list:
    for name1 in df1_name_list:
        if re.match(name1,name2):
            name2=name1
            break
    MappedName.append(name2)
df2['MappedName']=MappedName
df3=df1.merge(df2,left_on='name',right_on='MappedName',how='right').drop(['name_x','MappedName'],axis=1)
df4=df1.merge(df2,left_on='name',right_on='MappedName').drop(['name_x','MappedName'],axis=1)

print ('\ndf1\n',df1)
print ('\ndf2\n',df2)
print ('\ndf3\n',df3)
print ('\ndf4\n',df4)
```

The result looks like below

```
df1
   folder_name name
0          f1   aa
1          g1   bb

df2
      name icon MappedName
0      aa   i1         aa
1      bb   i2         bb
2   aadoq   i3         aa
3  bbaddd   i4         bb
4    ding   i5       ding

df3
   folder_name  name_y icon
0          f1      aa   i1
1          f1   aadoq   i3
2          g1      bb   i2
3          g1  bbaddd   i4
4         NaN    ding   i5

df4
   folder_name  name_y icon
0          f1      aa   i1
1          f1   aadoq   i3
2          g1      bb   i2
3          g1  bbaddd   i4
```

If you want NaN when you merge and there is no match, use the df3 example otherwise, use df4. For large datasets (millions of data points), this might not be efficient code.

Comment: Good solution! Much more robust than mine

Comment: @G.Anderson Your initial approach was factored into my solution. So, +1 for you.

Comment: sample_df = {'account':['a','b','a','c','a'],
    'return_type':['CTR','WO','T','CTR','WO'],
    'inception_date':['x','x','x','x','x']}

df = pd.DataFrame(sample_df)

df_ctr = df[df['return_type']=='CTR']

df2 = df[df['account'].isin(df_ctr.account)]
duplicate_t = df2[df2['return_type']=='T']

df_duplicate_removed = df[~df.isin(duplicate_t)].dropna()
df4

Comment: @ayush, what are you trying to say. It wasn't clear from your comment. Are you providing one more dataset as an example?

Answer (score 1):

I would explicitly add a column for prefix, merge, then remove the column after: (Note, this only works if all the data is as you posted, with a 2-character prefix)

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'folder_name':['f1','d1'],'name':['aa','bb']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name':['aa','bb','aaq','bbdfg'],'icon':[1,2,3,4]})

df2['prefix']=df2['name'].str[:2]

    name    icon    prefix
0   aa      1       aa
1   bb      2       bb
2   aaq     3       aa
3   bbdfg   4       bb

df3=df2.merge(df1, left_on='prefix', right_on='name').drop(['name_y','prefix'], axis=1)

df3

    name_x  icon    folder_name
0   aa      1       f1
1   aaq     3       f1
2   bb      2       d1
3   bbdfg   4       d1
```

Comment: This would work if the length of the folder_name is always two. The question did not make any such assumption.

Comment: The question did not state otherwise, and the provided data supports the code as written. If there are other concerns regarding the prefix, I believe it would be a separate question, or a matter of adapting this code to the actual condition. I will adit in the condition, though

Comment: suffix can be of any length

Comment: If suffix (assuming 'name' from dataframe 2) can be of any length, but the 'name' form dataframe is always going to be of length 2, this is a better solution than mine due to better performance and simplicity. The solution I created did not assume the length of the 'name' in dataframe 1 to be equal to 2.